# Getting error for create function in Lumen when table alias is already mentioned in model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen

Below is the code that I've tried:

```
class ClassName extends Model
{

 /**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
 protected $table = 'tablename as tn';

}

$data=array(
 'id'=>1,
 'name'=>'abc'
);
$obj= new ClassName();
$obj->create($data);
```

Error:

> string(434) "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'as tn

Comment: Question would benefit from more details giving the whole context of the error. It will be difficult to answer it in the present form. Make sure to check the guide on [How to ask good  questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your Model's table name declaration:
`protected $table = 'tablename as tn';`

Assuming that your database table name is `tn` You need to declare the `$table` variable like this:
`protected $table = 'tn';`

Comment: what if I need to take an alias with table name? As it is working fine for fetching data but causes an error while saving it to DB.